# cannot implicitly convert type List<Foo> to system.collections.generic.list<T>

Tags: c#, .net, generics, collections

I feel like I should really know the answer to this one... LOL!!

Why does returning a typed list within a function of generic list raises a compile error?

Example Code:

```
public List<T> Method<T>() where T : new()
{
   var items = new List<Foo>();

   return items;
}
```

Comment: should be: var items = new List<T>()

Comment: Because there is nothing that guarantees that Foo can be cast to T.

Comment: @Trioj Even if it could, it *still* wouldn't work.

Comment: @sTrenat - That still won't work, for the same reasons.

Comment: is this just a question or actual problem that you have somewhere in your code? If you want to return `Foo` then don't use generic return type.

Comment: @Lee, then he can call var items = new List<IFoo>();

Comment: @sTrenat - They can do `var items = new List<Foo>` now so the interface isn't helping and neither is the method.

Comment: Thank you all..   I think all your answers gave me just enough clues.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you call your function as:

```
List<Bar> items = Method<Bar>();
```

it would not work, since your method is going to give you a List of foo.

Another way to do this without generics would be to return a list of interfaces.

```
public List<iFoo> Method()
{
   var items = new List<Foo>();

   return items;
}
```

Comment: list does not support covariance. neither any type of class.

Comment: `List<T>` is invariant, so you can't assign a `List<Foo>` to a `List<IFoo>`.

Answer (score -1):

```
public interface IFoo
{
    int getAll();
}
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public Foo()
    {
    }
    public int getAll() => 1;
}

public List<T> Method<T>() where T : IFoo, new()
{
   var items = new List<T>();

   var foo = new T();
   items.Add(foo);
   return items;
}
var list = Method<Foo>();
```